# How can I get a SwiftUI Text view that goes beyond the screen bounds to align to leading edge?

Tags: text, swiftui, alignment

I'm trying this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct LeftToRight: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Color.black
            
            Text("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
                .font(.system(size: 450))
                .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                .foregroundColor(Color.pink)
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct LeftToRight_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LeftToRight()
    }
}
```

But the ZStack alignment is having no effect - the `Text` view center aligns (see screenshot).

[image: Screenshot showing the Text view aligned in the center]

I tried `.leading` alignment guides on the Text view itself, also to no effect.

So how can I align this Text view so that no matter how big it gets, it starts at the left edge and grows out past the right edge?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a safe solution - taking text frame natural (as it is by itself) just put it into overlay of container with explicit alignment

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Color.black
    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    .overlay(
        Text("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
            .font(.system(size: 45))
            .foregroundColor(Color.pink)
            .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
    , alignment: .leading)                                  // here !!
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, Asperi. The simpler answer by pawello2222 works fine but it feels odd setting the frame width to 0. But although this code works in isolation, I now need to integrate other things into the stack, so using an overlay is not going to work as a solution.

Comment: I tested and seen that `.frame(width: 0...` works, but it looks like SwiftUI bug, so in next version it might appear that Apple make your view frame real 0 and it is just disappears on your users' phones, otherwise I would not look for alternate safe solution. Just be aware.

Comment: yes, thank you. I'm not 100% sure about it - it does feel like a hack. I would like to find a solid solution that can keep the Text in the main body of the view, but just can't seem to see what it is.

Comment: @codewithfeeling True, my answer looks like a hack. I was just experimenting with `.frame` and noticed that the `alignment` parameter is only applied when the `width` is specified as well. It doesn't matter what value as there already is `.fixedSize(horizontal: true`.

Comment: @pawello2222 Thanks again for your suggestion. I am using it in my prototype for now and it's working fine. I am still working on this myself and trying to find a solution which feels solid. Interesting it does seem to be any fixed width <= screen width that works. I'll post any further findings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
struct LeftToRight: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Color.black

            Text("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
                .font(.system(size: 45))
                .foregroundColor(Color.pink)
                .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                .frame(width: 0, alignment: .leading) // <- add here
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

I noticed that the `alignment` parameter in the `.frame` modifier is only applied when the `width` is specified as well. It doesn't matter what value (that's why it's `0`) as there already is `.fixedSize(horizontal: true, ...)`. If you don't like it to be set to `0` you can easily specify some other *safer* value (eg. `100`).

Comment: Thanks very much for this. It works perfectly. Seems odd having to set the frame to 0, but it seems SwiftUI is still full of quirky hacks. I just need to check if there are any issues around doing it this way in terms of using the metrics of the Text view.